# How check if custom event was prevented

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In my code I need to interact with custom event after dispatched.

```
// ...
let customEvent = new CustomEvent('myevent', {
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true
});

button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  otherElement.dispatchEvent( customEvent );
  // at this point i neeed some help
  // if ( customEvent was canceled or prevented ) { do something }
});
```

How can check if it has been prevented/cancelled or another solution to get some "feedback" from event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lots of ways to do this. one way:

```
var isCanceled = !otherElement.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check for the [`defaultPrevented` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/defaultPrevented). Also the [`dispatchEvent` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) returns whether the default action is still to take place or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the Boolean [`defaultPrevented`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/defaultPrevented) in the event Object